# Open my visualForce page when user clicks on a custom button in a related list using salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

i am stuck on a issue.hope somebody can guide me.

I have created a **Custom Object** named **Hello**.

i have added 2 fields in it named **Lead** & **Accounts**.and they both are **lookups**.

Now i can see related list of my object under Accounts and leads as well

I wanna add a **custom button** to this **related list** that should open any other custom visual force page.

Now when i reached here:

```
Name>> Setup>> Create>>Objects>>Hello>>Custom buttons & links.
```

I created a new button.

Inside this i clicked **"List Button"**

I found an option **"Display in existing window using SideBar"**

I also chose **Content Source as VisualForcePage.**

but

there is nothing in the **Content Dropdown.**

**How i created the page**

```
Name>> Setup>> Develop >>Pages>>new>>MyNewPage


<apex:page standardController="Hello__c" extensions="MyExtentionFile">

</apex:page>
```

I tried many combinations of Standard and custom controllers but could not get success.
hope somebody can help me.

**I followed this link :**
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_custom_button.htm

Comment: can someone advice me what to do???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating a list button you'll also need to set the recordSetVar for it to show up as a potential content source for Hello__c.  You can see this in action in the doc link from your question.

```
<apex:page standardController="Hello__c" recordSetVar="hellos" extensions="MyExtensionFile">
  ... more code here ...
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Ralph gave you the right answer.

Check to see how you named your "Plural" form of your custom object Hello__c. If you accepted the defaults, you would have:

- Name: Hello
- Label: Hellos
- Object Name: Hello
- API Name: Hello_*c (or namespaceprefix*_Hello__c)

Then with the following page and class, Content Source as VisualForcePage will display it as selectable:

Class:

```
public with sharing class Hello_Controller 
{
    public Hello_Controller(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
    {
        controller.setPageSize(10);
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Hello__c" recordSetVar="Hellos" extensions="Hello_Controller">
</apex:page>
```